# Classification algorithms that work well with high dimensional dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a dataset with low data points but very high dimensions/features. I wanted to know if there's any classification algorithm that work well with such dataset without having to perform dimensionality reduction techniques such as PCA, TSNE?

```
df.shape
(2124, 466029)
```

Comment: Linear svm is also a choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the classic curse of dimensionality (or `p>>n`) problem (with `p` being the number of predictors and `n` the number of observations).

Many techniques have been developed to try and address this problem.
You can randomly restrict your variables (you select different random subsets) and then asses their importance using [cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29).

A preferable approach (imho) would be to use [ridge-regression, lasso, or elastic net](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf) for regularization, however be aware that their oracle properties are rarely satisfied in practice.

Finally, there are algorithms that are able to deal with a very large number of predictors (and [tweaks](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20304/why-do-we-pick-random-features-in-random-forest) in their implementation that improve the performance when p>>n).
Examples of such models are support vector machine or random forest.

There are many resources on the topic, which are freely available.
You can have a look at these [slides](http://www2.stat.duke.edu/~banks/218-lectures.dir/dmlect9.pdf) from Duke University for example.

### Oracle properties (Lasso)

I will not explain in a sound mathematical way but I'll briefly give you some intuition.

```
Y= dependent variable, your target  
X= regressors, your features  
ε= your errors
```

We define a shrinkage procedure *oracle* if it is asymptotically able to:

1. Identify the right subset of regressors (i.e. retain only the features that have a **true causal** relationship with your dependent variable.
2. Has an optimal estimation rate (I'll leave the details out)

There are three assumptions that, if satisfied, make the lasso *oracle*.

1. Beta-min condition: The coefficients of the "true" regressors is above a certain threshold.
2. Your regressors are uncorrelated with each other.
3. X and ε are normally distributed and homoskedatisc

**In practice you rarely have these assumptions satisfied.**

What happens in that case is that your shrinkage will not necessarily retain the *right* variables.
This implies that you can't make statistically sound inference on the final model (you can't say `X_1` explains Y for this and this other reason).

The intuition is simple. If assumption 1 is not satisfied one of the true variables might be incorrectly removed. If assumption 2 is not satisfied then a variable highly correlated with one of the true variables might be incorrectly retained in stead of the right one.

All in all, you shouldn't worry if your aim is forecasting. Your forecast will still be good! The only difference is that mathematically you can't say anymore that you are selecting the correct variables with probability -> 1.

PS: Lasso is a special case of elastic net, I vaguely remember that the oracle property of the elastic net has been proved as well but I might be wrong.
PPS: Corrections are appreciated as I haven't studied these things in a long while and there might be inaccuracies.

Comment: Can you explain what you meant by `oracle properties` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try a lasso/ridge/elastic net logistic regression.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try.